# Is this exercise on "Numerical Analysis" well written or it's just me?

Tags: numerical-methods

> Let $v(t)$ the velocity of an object in the direction of a forze defined by:
>   $$v(t) =
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   4t  & 0 \leq t\leq 4\\
>   16+(4-t)^2 & 4 \leq t\leq 14 \\
>  \end{array}
> \right.$$
>   i) Find the Work if apply $200N$ for any $t$ (Use Simpson's Rule).
>   ii) Make the velocity graph in function of time $(h=2)$
>   ii)Make the Displacement graph in function of time

i) I suppose that he need the total Work using Simpson's Rule on $v(t)$ using $h=2$ and then multiply the 200N to the result.

ii) i suppose that only i need graph $v(t)$, maybe the $h=2$ was a mistake writting the document

iii)I cant understand this point. how i can graph the Displacement in function of time using "numerical analysis" tools?

Comment: Have you covered splines yet in your class?

Comment: @user5713492 as interpolations?

Comment: Yeah, you would have data points for $t\in\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14\}$ from part ii) and then you could use Simpson's $1/3$ rule and one application of Simpson's $3/8$ rule to get displacement for $t\in\{0,4,8,14\}$. Then a natural spline for $t\in[0,4]$ and a spline where the first (or second) derivative is given at the endpoints for the rest of the domain. Just a thought...